# Get flat array when making mutliple selects in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I have a query that fetches some information from a table **AND** the count of related objects from another table. I have trouble expressing it in DQL, so it will return a **flat array**.

This example fetches the school, the name of the school and the number of students of each school:

```php
$qB = $this->createQueryBuilder('school')
$qB->leftJoin('school.students', 'students');
$qB->select([
    'partial school.{id, name}',
    'count(students) AS number_students',
]);
$qB->groupBy('school');
$qB->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I am expecting it to return:

```php
[
    [id => 1, 'name' => 'School A', 'number_students' => 5],
    [id => 2, 'name' => 'School B', 'number_students' => 3],
]
```

But I end up getting this:

```php
[
    [0 => [id => 1, 'name' => 'School A'], 'number_students' => 5],
    [0 => [id => 2, 'name' => 'School B'], 'number_students' => 3],
]
```

As a workaround it is possible to use `$qB->getQuery()->getScalarResult()`, but that then converts the variable names (e.g. The entity variable name `schoolName` is then converted to the column title in the database `school_name`), which means I would have to remap the fields again.

It is perhaps related in the way Doctrine treats entities. Here is the school entity of the example:

```php
class School {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $students;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DQL above seems like you end up with mixed results and that's Doctrine default behavior when using `$qB->getQuery()->getResult()`.

> `SELECT u, p.quantity FROM Users u...`
>
> Here, the result will again be an array of arrays, with each element
>   being an array made up of a User object and the scalar value
>   p.quantity.

I would try to debug the SQL generated and if I am right then there is your why. IMHO this behavior can not be changed but maybe I am wrong.

In this case the solution could be write a `protected` PHP function for flatten the array as you want to.

**Update:**

I haven't tried but *seems to be possible* to use [Doctrine Events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#the-event-system) to achieve this. There is not built-in Events for `preSelect` or `postSelect` however you can create your own Event and register it properly so you can call it at any point. As said before I didn't tried and I am not sure at all that this is possible using any Event (I might be wrong).

Just a side note, I would not try to over complicate this to much, you are adding a layer of complexity to the entity when you can do this easily on your controller by creating a private|public function that you can reuse at any point.

More info:

- [DQL Select Results](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#result-format)

Comment: I wonder if the Entity can be modified in a way so that Doctrine adds those fields to the main array.

Comment: I have updated my answer, see what I found and think there :)

Comment: Great idea thanks. But it is true that a private method might be the better approach, also for debugging.